# cors error depending on springboot version?

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, cors

I am trying to use stomp and sockjs in Springboot.

In my personal Gradle project (2.7.2), it works well without cors errors,

When I tried to apply it to my in-house project, I thought that the problem was that I was using version 2.2.1, so I upgraded the version to 2.6.4.
(Upgraded to the latest version on the in-house nexus.)

Has anyone had the same problem..?

cors config

```
@Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }
```

ERROR [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8jdy.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Nexus version doesn't seem to have any problems.

server add header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"

Comment: The cors setting is already added.

I will add content to the text.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).